# add total to the array

Tags: php, cakephp, php-5.3

the following algorithm add users to a company array. I want to add a total of user for any given company. Howd I go about doing that

```
public function all_company_information($id = null){
        $arrCompany = array();
        $arrCompany['company']= array();
        $arrData = array();
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->loadModel("User");
        $users = $this->User->find('all');
        foreach($users as $k => $user){


                if(!in_array($user['User']['company_id'], $arrCompany['company'])){

                    $arrCompany['company'][$user['User']['company_id']][] = $user;

                }else{

                $arrCompany['company'][$user['User']['company_id']][] = $user;

                }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Where does `$total++;` suddenly come from???

Comment: Which controller is this code in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a find on the Company model, then you can get a count of users easily.

```
$results = $this->Company->find('all');
foreach($results as $k => $company) {
    $results[$k]['Company']['user_count'] = count($company['User']);
}
```

Something along those lines. The returned results will be an array of `Company` records and each `Company` record will have a list of associated user records in the `User` key.

Comment: i did this 
$this->autoRender = false;
  $this->loadModel("User");
 $results = $this->User->Company->find('all');
foreach($results as $k => $company) {
    $results[$k]['Company']['user_count'] = count($company['User']);
}

Comment: If you are in the company controller you can just do `$this->Company->find(...)` If Company and User are associated, you don't have to loadModel, you can use model chaining. Make sure your associations are setup correctly. Do a `debug($results);` after the find call and see if the correct data is returned first of all. Post the debug output to bin.cakephp.org and paste the link here.